# How to configure mapcache to cache tile from a tms service

Tags: configuration, tms

I have a mapserver with mapcache on a server.

I know how to configure mapcache to cache tile from a wms service.

But I can't find anywhere how to configure mapcache to cache tile from a TMS service (openstreetmap https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png)

On the mapcache page https://mapserver.org/mapcache/index.html it is said 
"services WMS, WMTS, TMS, VirtualEarth/Bing and Google Maps requests: Supported Tile Services"

I see the line below on https://mapserver.org/mapcache/services.html#mapcache-services
"
To activate the TMS service, add these lines to the mapcache.xml configuration file:

`<service type="tms" enabled="true"/>`
"

but it's for a client to get tms tile from mapcache, not to mapcache to get the tile from a tms service

I Don't know if it is even possible, because I found no exemple.

**To get from a WMS I had the above**

```
<source name="name1" type="wms">
   <getmap>
      <params>
         <LAYERS>layer1</LAYERS>
      </params>
   </getmap>
   <http>
      <url>http://an_rul.com/ows/name1</url>
  </http>
</source>

<tileset name="name1">
   <source>name1</source>
   <cache>disk</cache>
   <grid>GoogleMapsCompatible</grid>

   <format>PNG</format>

   <metatile>5 5</metatile>
   <metabuffer>10</metabuffer>
   <expires>3600</expires>
</tileset>

<service type="wms" enabled="true">
   <full_wms>assemble</full_wms>
   <resample_mode>bilinear</resample_mode>
   <format>PNG</format>
   <maxsize>4096</maxsize>
   <forwarding_rule name="catch all">
   <http>
      <url>http://an_rul.com/ows/name1</url>
   </http>
   </forwarding_rule>
</service>

<service type="tms" enabled="true"/>
```

**For a TMS i'd like to have this sort of thing**

```
<source name="name1" type="tms">  <-- note the tms type i'd like
    <getmap>
       <params>
          <LAYERS>layer1 ?</LAYERS> <-- what layer can I put there  ?
       </params>
    </getmap>
    <http>
       <url>https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png ??</url> <-- which url should I write ??
   </http>
 </source>

 <tileset name="name1">
    <source>name1</source>
    <cache>disk</cache>
    <grid>GoogleMapsCompatible</grid>

    <format>PNG</format>

    <metatile>5 5</metatile>
    <metabuffer>10</metabuffer>
    <expires>3600</expires>
 </tileset>

 <service type="wms" enabled="true">
    <full_wms>assemble</full_wms>
    <resample_mode>bilinear</resample_mode>
    <format>PNG</format>
    <maxsize>4096</maxsize>
    <forwarding_rule name="catch all">
    <http>
       <url>http://an_rul.com/ows/name1</url>
    </http>
    </forwarding_rule>
 </service>

<service type="tms" enabled="true"/>
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapCache does not support TMS as a source. See https://mapserver.org/mapcache/config.html

> A source is a service mod-mapcache can query to obtain image data.
>   This is typically a WMS server accessible by a URL. (There are
>   currently only WMS, WMTS and mapfile as sources, though others may be
>   added later if the need arises, see Data Sources).

You can use MapProxy instead, it supports TMS sources (tiles) https://mapproxy.org/docs/nightly/sources.html

Comment: Thanks, yes I see that later that TMS is not supported